# How to use data.frame column values as function argument in dplyr mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running into a problem using the `mutate` functin of the `dplyr` package. I would like to use one column as argument of the `strptime` function

Example df:

```
    rdf=data.frame( 
        d="20180514",
        h=sample(1:25, 10)-1,
        m=sample(1:60, 10)-1
    )
    df = data.frame(
        stringtime = paste(rdf$d, rdf$h, rdf$m, sep=""),
        timezone = sample(rep(c("GMT", "CET"), 5), 10)
    )
    df 
          stringtime  timezone
    1   201805141701       CET
    2   201805140116       GMT
    .
    .
```

By intuition I wanted to run the command as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(timestamp = strptime(stringtime, tz=timezone, format="%Y%m%d%h%M")
```

Unluckily I get an error saying:

```
Error in [...]: invalid 'tz' value.
```

Does anybody have an idea what mistake I am making or if there would be an easy workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `POSIXlt` won't work in `mutate`.  use `as.POSIXct` or `ymd_hm` from `lubridate`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(stringtime,  format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))`

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

As there are different 'timezone', an option is to `group_split` and then specify the `first` 'timezone'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   group_split(timezone) %>% 
   map_df(~ .x %>% 
              mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(stringtime,
           format = "%Y%m%d%H%M",  tz = as.character(first(timezone)))))
```

---

According to `strptime`

> strptime converts character vectors to class "POSIXlt": its input x is first converted by as.character.

`POSIXlt` class is not supported in `mutate` as the underlying structure when `unclass`ed is a `list`

```
df %>%
    mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXlt(stringtime,  format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))
```

> Error: Column `timestamp` is of unsupported class POSIXlt; please use
>   POSIXct instead

Instead use `as.POSIXct`

```
df %>%
   mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(stringtime,  format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))
#   stringtime timezone           timestamp
#1  201805141314      GMT 2018-05-14 13:14:00
#2   20180514115      GMT 2018-05-14 11:05:00
#3  201805141434      CET 2018-05-14 14:34:00
#...
```

Comment: hi akrun. I was aware of that problem, ignored it for simplicity. Regarding your solution: How are you using the timezone now? This is the critical part of what I have to do.

Comment: thanks for the solution. It does work... in my case I run into the problem that it messes with the row order - i will have to find a solution for that.